# Access definitions on ref property with newtonsoft.json.schema

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I want to have access to the definitions in the schema in order to get the naming of the definition. I am using newtonsoft.json v11.01

I am building a c# converter for jsonschema to make a syntaxtree and compile it in order to get a typed version of the object at runtime.

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/arrays.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "xml remarks",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "fruits": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "fruit",
        "required": ["naam"],
        "properties": {
        "naam": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the fruit."
        }
        }
      }
    },
    "vegetables": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/veggie" }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "veggie": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [ "veggieName", "veggieLike" ],
      "properties": {
        "veggieName": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The name of the vegetable."
        },
        "veggieLike": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "Do I like this vegetable?"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the schema a reference is created with the name veggie. This is used in the property vegetable with a reference.

Json schema contains a definition on the root object but is doesn't have it on the property element. On the property element there is nothing identifiable to point to the right definition.

how do i find the right definition for the property?

Comment: Same question here https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/172, for ref purpose

Comment: did you get it working using $ref ? @Frans

Answer (score 0):

In general, in order to resolve a `json-pointer` (a $ref is a "uri-reference", and the part after the `#` is a "json-pointer"), you need to have access to the root of the json document.

So if you currently have a function that only gets an argument that points to the "properties" section, then you need to give that function a second argument that points to the root of the document.

(It gets more complicated when you're using a schema made up of more than one file; then you need a second argument that points to the roots of all the schema documents)

It's one of the more difficult parts of writing software that interprets json-schema files, especially if your language/library doesn't have support for json-pointers built-in - you'll need to write it yourself in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I can access the root object. unfortunately in the library i am currently using (newtonsoft.json) the reference or the pointer is part of the properties but it doesn't get filled in. I can manage when there is a Id in the reference. Unfortunately i can't require the use of id's